# What is causing this project to fail on Macbook Pro when It runs just fine on windows 10

Tags: nativescript

I have a nativescript application in windows that deploys to the emulator just fine, but when I git clone onto the MacBook Pro and run the same process, I get:

```
 new-host:nativescript jbaird$ tns run android
    Searching for devices...
    Starting Android emulator with image Nexus_5X_API_26
    Waiting for emulator device initialization...
    Executing before-liveSync hook from /Users/jbaird/Documents/development/gr8dates/Nativescript/hooks/before-liveSync/nativescript-angular-sync.js
    Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/jbaird/Documents/development/gr8dates/Nativescript/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
    Found peer TypeScript 2.4.2
    Preparing project...
    Project successfully prepared (Android)
    Building project...
    Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: spawn EACCES.
    Executing after-watch hook from /Users/jbaird/Documents/development/gr8dates/Nativescript/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know its not helpful but thats an ios issue/bug. I'd just use a windows pc

Comment: Are you saying this is a know issue on  IOS?

Comment: try this https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2626#issuecomment-287856590

Comment: im not sure if its a known issue, i just mean it looks like an ios/mac issue rather than nativescript or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a permission error. Therefore, all you need to do is give access to the the folder you are running your apps from. The process involves you to copy and paste the command below into your terminal. 
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /AppFolder
The command is an administrator command, therefore, you may have to insert your system password.

PS: Definitely, you hit enter and there will be a prompt for you to insert your password.
Let me know if you have any challenges with this solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
emulator-5554. Error is: spawn EACCES.emulator-5554. Error is: spawn EACCES.
```

Seems a permission error. You could solve it by:

- sudo,
- Or, by giving +x permision to your hooks folder?

Comment: Here are the permissions on hooks: drwxr-xrwx   7 jbaird  staff    238 Sep  5 09:49 hooks

Comment: What do you mean by sudo?

Comment: does the file /Users/jbaird/Documents/development/gr8dates/Nativescript/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js is executable? by sudo mean: sudo tns run android